# Cross table with conditional variables

Tags: r

I have following dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  X = sample(c(0.1, 2.3, NA), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Y = sample(c(0.23, 4.1, NA), 50, replace = TRUE))
```

and I want to generate following cross table:

[image]

maybe using

```
length(which())
```

The input is not that complex but I dont know how to arrange such a matrix.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cut` with `breaks` to divide data into buckets, use `count` to count their number in each bucket, get the data in wide format and use `janitor::adorn_totals` to add the total row and column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = cut, breaks = c(-Inf, 0.5, 5, Inf))) %>%
  count(X, Y) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = X, values_from = n) %>%
  janitor::adorn_totals(where = c('row', 'col'))

#          Y (-Inf,0.5] (0.5,5] NA Total
# (-Inf,0.5]          6       4  5    15
#    (0.5,5]          7       6  5    18
#       <NA>          5       9  3    17
#      Total         18      19 13    50
```

Comment: Okay i thought this would be the answer i´m looking for but i´m not sure anymore. For example "> length(which(df$X < 0.5 & df$Y < 0.5))" gives me 4 but in your table it shows a 6.  Why is that?

Comment: For me `length(which(df$X < 0.5 & df$Y < 0.5))` returns 6 which matches the shown output. I think the seed algorithm has changed recently so we might get different results based on the R version we are on. Run the above code on the data that you have and see what numbers do you get in the output and check if they match.

Comment: Thank you, i got it! Is there any chance we can get the <NA> in the first column turned to NA like the column name?

Comment: That is just how R displays `NA` values. If you store the above output in a new object say `df1` and check `df1$Y` you'll see them in the same way as the column name.

Comment: you can replace the `count` and `pivot_wider` commands with the single line `janitor::tabyl(Y, X, show_missing_levels = FALSE)`